# How do I call DynamicInvoke on an Expression<Action<T>> using Compile?

Tags: c#, reflection, lambda

Why doesn't this work?

```
namespace InvokeTest
{
    public class MethodInvoker
    {
        public static void Execute<T>(Expression<Action<T>> call)
        {
            // Parameter count mismatch
            call.Compile().DynamicInvoke();

            // Also attempted this:
            //call.Compile().DynamicInvoke(1);
            // but it threw: "Object of type 'System.Int32' cannot be converted to type 'InvokeTest.TestClass'."
        }
    }

    public class TestClass
    {
        public TestClass()
        { }

        public void DoSomething(int num)
        {
            System.Console.WriteLine("It works");
        }

        public void KickOff()
        {
            MethodInvoker.Execute<TestClass>(m => m.DoSomething(1));
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An `Action<T>` is the same as a `delegate void F<T>(T t)`. That is, an `Action<T>` is an method that has return type `void` and consumes instances of `T`.

When you call

```
MethodInvoker.Execute<TestClass>(m => m.DoSomething(1));
```

you have set the type parameter `T` to be `TestClass`. Therefore, you need to pass in a parameter, and that parameter has to be instance of `TestClass`.

This is why in the first case you get a parameter count mismatch, and in the second case the compiler wants to convert the parameter to an instance of `TestClass`. You need to pass one parameter, and that parameter needs to be an instance of `TestClass`.

Note that your action is

```
m => m.DoSomething(1).
```

So your action takes an instance of `TestClass` which you are parameterizing by `m` and invokes `m.DoSomething(1)` on that instance. Now, when you dynamically invoke this method, you need to be giving it an instance of `TestClass`. You aren't doing that.

Answer (score 1):

Since you defined the parameter type

```
Expression<Action<T>>
```

the function will require expression in accordance with the following delegate:

```
Action<TestClass>
```

which is:

```
public void SampleMethod(TestClass a)
```

Based on this the correct invocation should look like this:

```
var t = new TestClass();
call.Compile().DynamicInvoke(t);
```